# to wait on somebody or to wait for somebody

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

In a question I had to select the correct sentence from among the 4 options. Though I could eliminate two options but got stuck in two other options. They were as follows

> It is the duty of a housewife to **wait on** the guest.

> It is the duty of a housewife to **wait for** the guest.

because I think both of them are correct.

But I have to choose only one, an I am unable to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both grammatical, but they normally mean completely different things:

1. to *wait* ***on*** somebody
   This means to serve somebody and attend to their needs.
   The serving staff at the restaurant had all been trained on the proper way to *wait* ***on*** their hungry customers and get them whatever they wanted.
2. to *wait* ***for*** somebody
   This means to be available and present when somebody arrives.
   They all had other things to do, but they put them on hold while they were *waiting* ***for*** the dignitary to arrive. None of them wanted to be absent during the grand entrance.

One thing can happen after another. After waiting *for* someone, once they've arrived, you can then wait *on* them.

Note that some people use *wait on* in the above sense of *wait for*; however, the reverse is not the case.